# ProviderError: transaction would cause overdraft when using Uniswap V3 router on Goerli testnet

Tags: hardhat, uniswap, gas-estimate, uniswapv3, goerli

I tried to call a smart contract (`UniswapV3Swap.sol`) from another smart contract (`UniswapV3Connector.sol`). I want to call the `swapExactInputSingleHop` from `UniswapV3Connector.sol`, however, **the transactions kept reverting due to overdraft**. I used hardhat for testing the smart contract and deployed the `UniswapV3Swap.sol (address: 0x90e35Fb43c6A2e6a110da943825eb91371a1D87e)` on the Goerli network. Here is the error that I got:

> 1. UniswapV3Connector 
>    Swap exact WETH to DAI:
>    ProviderError: transaction would cause overdraft

Here is my `UniswapV3Swap.sol`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later

pragma solidity ^0.7.6;
pragma abicoder v2;

import "./interfaces/IWETH.sol";
import "./interfaces/IERC20.sol";
import "./interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";

// deployed on Goerli network: 0x90e35Fb43c6A2e6a110da943825eb91371a1D87e

contract UniswapV3Swap {
    
    uint24 public fee;
    address public owner;

    ISwapRouter private constant router =
        ISwapRouter(0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564);
    
    constructor (uint24 _fee){
        fee = _fee;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function changeFee(uint24 _newFee) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        fee = _newFee;
    }

    function swapExactInputSingleHop(address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin)
        external
    {
        IERC20(tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);
        IERC20(tokenIn).approve(address(router), amountIn);
        ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter
            .ExactInputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: tokenIn,
                tokenOut: tokenOut,
                fee: fee,
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountIn: amountIn,
                amountOutMinimum: amountOutMin,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });
        router.exactInputSingle(params);
    }

    function swapExactOutputSingleHop(address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint amountOut, uint amountInMax)
        external
    {
        IERC20(tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountInMax);
        IERC20(tokenIn).approve(address(router), amountInMax);
        ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter
            .ExactOutputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: tokenIn,
                tokenOut: tokenOut,
                fee: fee,
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountOut: amountOut,
                amountInMaximum: amountInMax,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });
        uint amountIn = router.exactOutputSingle(params);

        if (amountIn < amountInMax) {
            IERC20(tokenIn).approve(address(router), 0);
            IERC20(tokenIn).transfer(msg.sender, amountInMax - amountIn);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `UniswapV3Connector.sol`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later
pragma solidity ^0.7.6;

import "./interfaces/IWETH.sol";
import "./interfaces/IERC20.sol";
import "./UniswapV3Swap.sol";

contract UniswapV3Connector{
    // IUniswapV3Swap private immutable routerHelper;
    address public uniswapV3SwapAddress;
    UniswapV3Swap private uniswapV3Swap;
    constructor(address _router){
        uniswapV3SwapAddress = _router;
        uniswapV3Swap = UniswapV3Swap(_router);
    }
    
    function swapExactInputSingleHop(address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin) external {
        IERC20(tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);
        IERC20(tokenIn).approve(address(uniswapV3SwapAddress), amountIn);

        uniswapV3Swap.swapExactInputSingleHop{gas: 3000000}(tokenIn, tokenOut, amountIn, amountOutMin);
    }
}
```

And lastly, this is my `test-swap.js`

```
const {ethers} = require("hardhat")
const {assert, expect} = require("chai")

const WETH9 = "0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6";
const DAI = "0x11fE4B6AE13d2a6055C8D9cF65c55bac32B5d844";

describe("UniswapV3Connector", () => {

  let accounts;
  let contractFactory;
  let contract;
  let weth
  let dai
  let provider

  beforeEach(async function (){
    accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
    provider = ethers.provider

    // connect to interface
    weth = await ethers.getContractAt("IWETH", WETH9)
    dai  = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", DAI)

    contractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("UniswapV3Connector")
    contract = await contractFactory.deploy("0x90e35Fb43c6A2e6a110da943825eb91371a1D87e")
    await contract.deployed() 
    console.log("Deployed successfully") 
  })

  it("Swap exact WETH to DAI", async () => {
  
    const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.001")
    const amountOutMin = 1;

    await weth.connect(accounts[0]).deposit({value: amountIn})
    await weth.connect(accounts[0]).approve(contract.address, amountIn)

    await contract.swapExactInputSingleHop(WETH9, DAI, amountIn, amountOutMin)

    console.log("DAI balance:", await dai.balanceOf(accounts[0].address))
  })
})
```